# How to wait for async API calls in loop

Tags: flutter

I have a widget where on initState, I need to loop over some controls and load data via an API.
I want to use/reference this data in the widget control key.

This is summary of code initializing data.

```
 List<dynamic> controlData = [];

  @override
  initState(){
    loadAllOptionData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void loadAllOptionData() async {
    List<dynamic> listDataControls = [];

    Future.wait(widget.fields.where((element) => element['header'] !=null).map((e) async {
      if(e['uitype']==7){
        List<dynamic> options = await ApiManager.getListData(widget.tableId, e);
        listDataControls.add({e['data'] : options});
      }
    }).toList());

    this.setState(() {
      controlData= listDataControls;
    });
  }
```

In the widget render tree, I have this check

```
if(controlData.length>0){
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Text('has data')
            );
          }
```

Right now, it's not working, as it never shows "has data". How do I get this data loaded, such that I can reference in widget tree?

Comment: `await Future.wait(...` and use the returned `Future` from `loadAllOptionData()` method inside `FutureBuilder`

Comment: ugh, just forgot to put the await in front of future.wait . That solved the issue, thx!